# Netbeans indention is not working properly for switch case php

Tags: php, netbeans, coding-style, switch-statement, phpcodesniffer

I am using netbeans 7.1.2. Normally i'm using netbeans to indent my code. I have changed the **"tabs and intends"** options in **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting** section. It is working for all the control statements while running the file in codesniffer.But for the switch case the standard should be

```
switch ($action) {
case "1":
    break;
case "2":
    break;
}
```

But it is intending like this

```
switch ($action) {
    case "1":
        break;
    case "2":
        break;
}
```

so in codesniffer it is showing the indention error. Can anyone please tell be how to indent switch statement in netbeans?

Comment: what are your settings in the formatting section? this works fine for me in the same version of netbeans with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, when you insert a curly brace `{` NetBeans as well as most all other IDEs auto-indent for formatting purposes. I have never experienced this problem for my self. What standard are you coding to?